# cannot get clickoutside to work in Fancybox

Tags: fancybox

Having changed every instance of clickoutside to "true" in my jquery.fancybox.js for my site https://byjohan.se, Fancybox still won't close when clicking outside the image. I first thought it had to do with me opening Fancybox by default in fullscreen but after changing that the problem still persists. What am I missing or doing wrong?

I'd be happy with every bit of help I could get :)

//Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to use `clickSlide` option, because `clickOutside`option defines action when clicked outside the slide (if you have not resized and/or repositioned slider area, then you actually can not click outside).

Comment: I've actually changed both clickoutside and clickslide to true, but to no avail. I even tried changing clickcontent but nothing happens... It seems it doesn't react at all to the changes.

Comment: Did you really just set to true? If you want to close, then set "close" (see https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/blob/master/src/js/core.js#L317)

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that, but apparantly not in every instance. It however work, now. Again thanks